# Hbox inside Vbox

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I am trying to place Hboxes inside a Vbox, which means each Hbox should be a row, but I am getting this result

[image: Screenshot]

The label first name and its corresponding text box should be one row, and the last name should be another row.

What can I do to make each hbox become a separate row in the vbox.

My code:

```
public class App extends Application {

     Button btn1=new Button("Add");
    Button btn2=new Button("Subtract");
    Button btn3=new Button("Multiply");
    Button btn4=new Button("Devide");
    Button reset=new Button("reset");                                            //reset X?
    TextField T1=new TextField();
    TextField T2=new TextField();
    TextField T3=new TextField();
    Label L1=new Label("Number 1: ");
    Label L2=new Label("Number 2: ");
    Label L3=new Label("Result: ");
    Label L=new Label();
    Label I=new Label();
    Button create=new Button("Create");
    Button update=new Button("Update");
    Label idlabel=new Label("Id ");
    Label fname=new Label("First Name ");
    Label lname=new Label("Last Name ");
    TextField firstName=new TextField();
    TextField lastName=new TextField();




    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {    

        HBox H4=new HBox();
        H4.getChildren().add(create);
        H4.getChildren().add(update);
        H4.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        H4.setSpacing(3);


        VBox V=new VBox();
        V.getChildren().add(H4);
        V.setSpacing(6);

        HBox fnameBox=new HBox();
        fnameBox.getChildren().add(fname);
        fnameBox.getChildren().add(firstName);
        fnameBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        fnameBox.setSpacing(5);

        HBox lnameBox=new HBox();
        fnameBox.getChildren().add(lname);
        fnameBox.getChildren().add(lastName);
        fnameBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        fnameBox.setSpacing(5);

        VBox Form=new VBox();
        Form.getChildren().add(fnameBox);
        Form.getChildren().add(lnameBox);


        create.setOnAction((e->  
        {
            Scene scene = new Scene (Form, 500, 750);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Create Student");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        }
        ));



        Scene scene = new Scene (V, 500, 750);
        primaryStage.setTitle("calculator");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: for your next question: a) always provide a [mcve] - mind the __M__ , that is remove everything that's unrelated (here: just the two layouts and the 4 controls added) b) learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: Sound like something that is better suited for `GridPane`. https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your problem

```
HBox lnameBox=new HBox();
fnameBox.getChildren().add(lname);
fnameBox.getChildren().add(lastName);
fnameBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
fnameBox.setSpacing(5);
```

You create `lnameBox` but use `fnameBox` instead. So `lnameBox` does not have children